# Launching nose with --with-gae option raises ValueError for missing lib/ipaddr

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nosetests

Setting up the testing framework and I can't seem to get past this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nosetests", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/core.py", line 118, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/core.py", line 135, in parseArgs
    self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/config.py", line 338, in configure
    self.plugins.configure(options, self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 271, in configure
    cfg(options, config)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 94, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 162, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/nosegae.py", line 80, in configure
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 76, in <module>
    DIR_PATH = get_dir_path(os.path.join('lib', 'ipaddr'))
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 66, in get_dir_path
    'file and %s.' % sibling)
ValueError: Could not determine directory that contains both, this file and lib/ipaddr.
```

It's a correct error coming from `dev_appserver.py`... there is no `lib/ipaddr` in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Why is `nosetests` triggering the raising of this error? Why does `dev_appengine` try to look for `lib/ipaddr` in the first place?

Comment: unanswered @ http://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/issues/detail?id=61

Comment: i opened the ticket on the link above. you can install those packages on 2 different python version and by switching between lets say `nose tests-2.6` and `nosetests-2.7` it works for now (ugly workaround but better than nothing). still waiting for an answer on the issue tracker.

Comment: is there a simple way to switch versions for this purpose?

Comment: what do you mean? besides having the command in the command line once for each version and hitting arrow up to use it again?

Comment: i assume by 2.6 and 2.7 you mean python version... i guess my question is what's the command to switch an appengine product's python version -- is it just the runtime line-item in app.yaml?

Comment: in case anyone wants to know how to install `nosetests-2.6` checkout `easy_install-2.6`

Comment: thanks again aschmid00 - your temporary solution works for me.

Comment: its annoying anyway... lets hope this will get fixed soon.

Comment: The same happens with nosegunit plug-in. So, I don't think it's a problem with the plug-ins themselves but rather a problem with the GAE  environment on OSX.

Comment: In fact, in dev_appserver.py you can see the code where it's breaking:`dir_paths = [os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))),
               os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))]
  for dir_path in dir_paths:
    sibling_path = os.path.join(dir_path, sibling)`